# SQL help to count number of locations for each item/branch

Tags: oracle, group

I'm a SQL rookie, and am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do the following.  I have a table that contains item information by branch.  Within a branch an item can be in multiple locations.  The data I need to extract needs to include a column that provides the total number of locations (count) the item is associated with for a given branch.

Output would look something like this:
[image]

I'm guessing this is a sub query, but to be honest I'm not sure how to get started... order in which this is done (subquery group by first, then join, etc)

In purely logical terms:

```
SELECT
a.Branch,
a.Item,
a.Loc,
COUNT(a.Branch||a.Item) AS 'LocCount' 
FROM BranchInventoryFile a
GROUP BY a.Branch,a.Item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle this by using Oracle's `Count Analytical` functions found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/count-analytic-function). Be sure to read up on `WINDOW`/`Partitioning` functions as this unlocks quite a bit of functionality in SQL.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
  a.BRANCH, 
  a.ITEM, 
  a.LOC, 
  COUNT(a.ITEM) OVER (PARTITION BY a.BRANCH, a.ITEM) AS LOC_COUNT 
FROM 
  BRANCH a;
```

**Result:**

```
| BRANCH | ITEM |  LOC | LOC_COUNT |
|--------|------|------|-----------|
|    100 |    A | 1111 |         2 |
|    100 |    A | 1112 |         2 |
|    200 |    A | 2111 |         1 |
|    200 |    B | 1212 |         2 |
|    200 |    B | 1212 |         2 |
|    300 |    A | 1222 |         1 |
```

**SQL Fiddle:**
[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1cec60/5)

Answer (score 0):

> total number of locations (count) the item is associated with for a given branch

The way you described it, you should

- remove location from query:

  ```
  SQL> with branchinventoryfile (branch, item, location) as
    2    (select 100, 'A', 1111 from dual union all
    3     select 100, 'A', 1112 from dual union all
    4     select 200, 'A', 2111 from dual
    5    )
    6  select branch,
    7         item,
    8         count(distinct location) cnt
    9  from BranchInventoryFile
   10  group by branch, item;

      BRANCH I        CNT
  ---------- - ----------
         100 A          2
         200 A          1

  SQL>
  ```
- if you leave `location` in `select`, you have to `group by` it (and get wrong result):

  ```
    6  select branch,
    7         item,
    8         location,
    9         count(distinct location) cnt
   10  from BranchInventoryFile
   11  group by branch, item, location;

      BRANCH I   LOCATION        CNT
  ---------- - ---------- ----------
         100 A       1111          1
         200 A       2111          1
         100 A       1112          1

  SQL>
  ```
- or include locations, but aggregate them, e.g.

  ```
    6  select branch,
    7         item,
    8         listagg(location, ', ') within group (order by null) loc,
    9         count(distinct location) cnt
   10  from BranchInventoryFile
   11  group by branch, item;

      BRANCH I LOC                         CNT
  ---------- - -------------------- ----------
         100 A 1111, 1112                    2
         200 A 2111                          1

  SQL>
  ```

Comment: I do need the locations in the result, but the second example you provided is giving me an error... DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Which database version do you use? LISTAGG was introduced in Oracle 11g. I edited answer which now shows sample data and result returned by both queries (read: code is OK, if it is supported in your database).

Comment: Thank you but, that won't work for me.  Need to have a row for each location instead of as a list in each row.

Comment: As I said (and now illustrated it - see 2nd piece of code above): you can include LOCATION in SELECT, but then you have to GROUP BY LOCATION as well, and it'll return **wrong result** (all counts will be **1**).

Comment: Understood, this is why I am asking for help.